# How to reinstall Ubuntu linux 12.04, after I reinstalled windows 7

Tags: 12.04

I had Ubuntu and Windows both on my pc. I reinstalled Windows 7 and Ubuntu just disappeared after that.

When I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, it is showing errors. And I am new to Ubuntu, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Ubuntu may still be there take a look at this question: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/107450).  If this does not help edit your question to include the specific errors you get.

Answer (score 2):

You can boot your computer with ubuntu installation media (DVD/USB) and try [boot-repair](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (2nd option) program to fix grub. Do not worry your ubuntu partition should be there unless you overwrite with windows 7

Comment: But ubuntu is not opening...

Comment: If you repaired grub and its is not openning, this shows that your ubuntu installation damaged. "When I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, it is showing errors." this mesage shows that. What kind of errors, it shows?